# Parameterized query - error when executing a query

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I've recently been trying to figure out a way to get parameterized queries to work and i think i'm almost there but seem to be getting an error when executing my query

Here's the code

```
Dim LogData2 As sterm.MarkData = New sterm.MarkData()

Dim query As String = ("Select * from openquery (db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor=@investor')")

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@investor", 34)

Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(query)
```

I've debugged it and it doesn't seem to be putting the parameter into the query.

```
"Select * from openquery (db, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor=@investor')"
```

That's what i get when i debug the line `Dim drCode2a As DataSet = LogData2.StermQ3(query)`

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

Here's how I solved my problem

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server='h'; user id='w'; password='w'; database='w'; pooling='false'")

conn.Open()

Dim query As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @investor varchar(10), @sql varchar(1000) Select @investor = 69836 select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(db,''SELECT * FROM table WHERE investor = ''''' + @investor + ''''''')' EXEC(@sql)", conn)

dgBookings.DataSource = query.ExecuteReader
dgBookings.DataBind()
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Jamie taylor I will try to answer your question again.

You are using OpenQuery becuase you are probably using a linked DB

Basically the problem is the OpenQuery Method takes a string you cannot pass a variable as part of the string you sent to OpenQuery.

You can format your query like this instead.  The notation follows servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename.  If you are using a linked server via odbc then omit databasename and schemaname, as illustrated below

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("your SQL Connection String")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * db...table where investor = @investor"
    Dim parameter As SqlParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
    parameter.DbType = SqlDbType.Int
    parameter.ParameterName = "@investor"
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    parameter.Value = 34
```

Comment: I've done that but without the `...` and I get `must declare @investor` and if i do it with the `...` then I get `invlaid column prefix`

Comment: I'm now getting `Property access must assign to the property or use its value.`

Comment: @Jamie Taylor ... Set the parameter direction

Comment: I'm now getting `'SqlDataParameter' is not defined.`

Comment: @Jamie Taylor ... I found some typos in the code I wrote but what is there now works, as I just tested it.

Comment: I've never accessed databases like this what kind of thing should i be putting in the `SqlConnection()` bit? Sorry i'm really new to all this appreciate the help so far

Comment: @Jamie Taylor ...If you have never setup the SQL Connection then what were you connecting to?

Comment: The guy who previously did this used to have this `Dim LogData2 As sterm.MarkData = New sterm.MarkData()` and it seems to work

Comment: @Jamie Taylor  ... Clearly something is set up that is custom and you need to understand its functionality before trying to add new

Comment: I've found my connection string now but how do i databind that to a datagrid?

Comment: @Jamie Taylor ...I was happy to help you with a few things. But I am not going to write every bit of code for you. I truely suggest that you begin reading up on the components you are using

Comment: That's fine thanks for your help on everything i'll look around for a way to databind it - without databinding it i'm unable to tell if what you gave me works so i will update the question when i find this information - thanks again

Comment: @Jamie Taylor - you can get a row count on your dataset to see if it is returning any records.  Dim i as int = drCode2a.Tables(0).Row.Count

Comment: @John Hartsock I seem to be getting a `must declare @investor` with the code you have supplied. For some reason linking to a server screws things up with parameters

Comment: @John Hartsock thanks for all the help you provided I have now added the solution to my problem above